# Is is possible to extend constructors in c#?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am wondering if there is an existing class (such as UIColor from Monotouch) if there is a way to extend a constructor. That would make working with the library we have easier.

```
public static class UIColorExtender
{
    public UIColor(string hex)
    {
        this = ConvertHexToUIColor(hex); // This isn't necessarily the code, just filler.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only no, you have an instance constructor on a static class.  Do yourself a huge favor and grab clr via C# by Jeff Richter.  Skip the first few chapters until you read the rest of the book.

Comment: @Will he has a constructor in a static class because he's trying to declare an extension method which you do in a static class... I don't think that code compiles so it doesn't matter, it's not like it will end up in his project. Of course he doesn't have `this` for the first arg so it's not really clear but it's called UIColorExtender.

Comment: You could also create a factory to create the objects for you.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: "constructor" was wrong, my bad.  Went by the title.  This question, it confuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this question is trying to achieve the same as you?
[UIColor from Hex in Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310917/uicolor-from-hex-in-monotouch)

When looking at the UIColor class, it seems that it mostly uses a factory pattern when using other formats than just 4 float values for R, G, B and alpha:

```
UIColor.FromHSB(float, float, float)
UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(float, float)
```

..and many more

So I think the best solution would be like Luis' in the question above.

Comment: This is what we went with, as it makes the most sense in the place we are using it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no such way presently in C#. Inherit from the class and use your own constructor logic. Use the new class in place of the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can't be extended. You can inherit from the class and implement your own or, if the class in question isn't full of read-only properties, create an initialization method to call after the constructor.