# Xamarin iOS bind category class method

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

There are plenty examples in the wild on how to bind instance methods in objc category, but I have yet to find how would one bind class method. For example if I have this category:

```
@interface UIColor (Awesome)
+ (UIColor *)colorFromHex:(NSString *)hex;
@end
```

And if I try to bind it like this:

```
[Category, BaseType(typeof(UIColor))]
interface UIColor_Awesome
{
    [Static, Export ("colorFromHex:")]
    UIColor ColorFromHex(string hex);
}
```

I'll get this method after Xamarin's code generation magic happens:

```
public static UIColor ColorFromHex (this UIColor This, string hex)
```

And I have no idea what to do with first arg - I don't have an instance to call this method on.
How should I correctly write APIDefinition for this situation or how should I use generated method?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps another person.

EDITED:

I had the same problem, I was binding a method in category.

Then, I found a solution posted [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41573/binding-objective-c-class-extension-that-contains-a-constructor) that just add the method to the constructor of the "base class".

In my case, I had a category of a `UIView` that is equivalent to the question. You just must remove the word "category".

Following the Emil's question:

```
[BaseType(typeof(UIColor))]
interface UIColor_Awesome
{
    [Static, Export ("colorFromHex:")]
    UIColor ColorFromHex(string hex);
}
```

Comment: Please do not post a link to another side, if there is a solution post it here!

Answer (score -1):

That is an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). They allow you to extend / augment a class without having to subclass it or without having the code for it. `This` will be the instance of the class they they are called on.

```
var color = new UIColor(); // or some reference to a UIColor
var newColor = color.ColorFromHex("#FF0000");
```

or you can use it just like a static method (even though this is not how they are intended):

```
var color = new UIColor();
var newColor = UIColor.ColorFromHex(color, "#FF0000");
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10310917/1134836) is another question about getting the hex color from UIColor.

*Disclaimer, I didn't compile the code.

Comment: So the solution is to provide a stub instance?

Comment: Is your main question how to use the extension method or are you really just wanting to know how to convert a hex to ui color?

Comment: Main question is about how to bind a class method in category, colors were used as an example.
Just in case - class methods don't have an instance to work with

Comment: You would want to provide the instance of whatever class you want to perform the method against.

Comment: That's not always true and example above proves that. I don't need any intermediate instances of color to create new color from string, in objc it will be done like this:
`UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorFromHex:@"0xff0000"];`

Comment: It is for the extension method that you said it generates. Btw, what is generating it?

Comment: Added more details in question - Xamarin generates this class extension, based on entry in APIDefinition.